# Dates for each month in separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create dates for each month individually. I have done my bit of work but looking for optimised code.

Steps

```
Create a Spreadsheet and change the name from "Sheet1" to "Year"

Column A ColumnB
2014 January
     February
     March
     April
     May
     June
     July
     August
     September
     October
     November
     December
```

Now copy the below to VBA module

```
Sub GenerateDate()
  Dim amonth As String
  Dim col, cola As String
  Dim ayear As Integer
  For x = 1 To 12
     Worksheets("Year").Select
     Worksheets("Year").Activate
     '//this will add every month worksheet
      Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Cells(x, 2)
      Worksheets("Year").Activate
     '//get month name to string called amonth//
     amonth = Cells(x, 2).Value
    '//get year to variable type int called ayear//
     ayear = Cells(1, 1).Value
    '//activate month sheet
    Worksheets(amonth).Activate
   '//insert date 1st day of each month in cell A1
   Cells(1, 1).Value = DateSerial(ayear, x, 1)
   '//select 'A1' cell values
   Cells(1, 1).Select
   '// pass A1 value to a my_date
   my_date = Cells(1, 1).Value
   '//change the format of the date in A1 cell
   Selection.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy;@"
   '//count number of days in month for the date in A1
   numof_days = Day(DateSerial(Year(my_date), Month(my_date) + 1, 1) - 1)
   '// col a and cola are two strings holds sting values "A" and "A1" respectively
  col = "A"
  cola = "A1"
   '//Final value is range to be used to fill the dates
  Final = col & numof_days
  '//fill dates from A1 to Final cell values
  With Range("A1")
 .AutoFill Destination:=Range(cola, Final), Type:=xlFillDays
 End With
  '//auto fit the entire "A" column
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Next x
 End Sub
```

My output

Creates new sheet for each month and generates dates for that month only.

Comment: If your current code is working and you are just looking for optimization consider asking your question at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - it's a site designed specifically for code reviews. Please make sure you point out which part of your code needs optimization and why.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step you may find it more effective to add application.screenupdating = false at the beginning of your code and then application.screenupdating = true at the end. This will speed up your code. You may also consider doing the same for application.displayalerts.